# Python Flask collapsible/expandable dynamic table

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask

I am building a table in flask with rows that are collapsible. A row may have several elements underneath it that will all collapse on clicking. It works fine if I just hardcode values but when I am populating the table using a loop with data from a python dictionary, it does not work. The first row's first child collapses instead of all the correct row's children collapsing. Below should be sufficient code to reproduce the issue.
`elements` is a dictionary where key is a string and value is a list of tuples.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{%for k, v in elements.items()%}

<tbody>
<tbody class="labels">
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <label for="i">{{k}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="i" id="i" data-toggle="toggle">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>

{%for desc in v%}
<tbody class="hide">
<tr>

    <td>{{desc[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{desc[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{desc[2]}}</td>
    <td>
        <button>trigger</button>
    </td>
    <td>{{desc[3]}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}

</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
        $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label for="i">{{k}}</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="i" id="i" data-toggle="toggle">
```

Accidentally wasn't changing the for, name, id fields.

Needed to update those as variables as well so looks like

```
<label for={{k}}>{{k}}</label>
<input type="checkbox" name={{k}} id={{k}} data-toggle="toggle">
```